# Discord.js guildMemberAdd event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, discord.js, event-handling

I am trying to code a Discord bot for my personal server. I am using Discord.js and I have been following the discord.js guide.

I have now an event handler but when I add a file for another event, the code of this module is not executing. The event I am trying to trigger is the join of a new member in my server.

I have 2 important files : index.js which runs the corpse of my code and guildMemberAdd.js which is my event module for when a new member joins the server.

`index.js`:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

`guildMemberAdd.js`:

```js
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.GuildMemberAdd,
    async execute(member) {
        console.log(member);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` intent enabled, the `GuildMemberAdd` event won't fire. You'll need to add the `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` (and probably `GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences`) too:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
  ],
});
```

In discord.js v13, it should be:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
  ],
});
```